# Running error Java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run this code:

```
package jmv;

public class euler3 {
    static int x=1;
    static long z = 600851475143L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(isPrime(123454321));
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int p){
        for(int y=1 ; y<x ;){
            if(x%y == 0){
                return true; 
            }else{
                return false;
            }           
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It always returns false. Why?
Thank you for your help. I very much appereciate every answer that I am given however i appereiciate the better ones more.

Comment: Read some basic tutorials in java or read some good book in java like
Head First Java that will surely help you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is you are NOT checking p, the parameter given to the function isPrime().

It should be like that:

```
package jmv;

public class euler3 {
    static int x=1;
    static long z = 600851475143L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPrime(123454321));
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int p){
        if (p%2 == 0) {
            return false;
        } else  {
            for(int y=3 ; y<p ; y=y+2){
                if(p%y == 0){
                    return false; 
                }          
            }
        }
        return true;
     }
 }
```

You need to check if 2 divides p first, because an even number may be passed to the function. Then you just need to check the odd number >=3. But this is basic mathematics and I'm sure you just forgot it.

Doing this you save many tests. If you test with y++ you will be checking for every even number and this is not necessary, for if a number is even and greater than 2, it is NOT prime.

Hope it helps!

Comment: In fact, you could optimize even more by testing only up to (p/2), because there is a well known theorem stating that if y is prime and p divides an integer p, then y<=(p/2).

As a mathematician, I'm much more concerned about these things than normal people.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int y=1 ; y<x ;){<-- loop never gets executed as 1<1 will be always false
```

Moreover you are not incrementing `y` change it to `for(int y=1 ; y<x ;y++)` and assign specific value to `x` say `x=10` must be `>y`.

And yes as you are passing p as parameter you must want to do `for(int y=1 ; y<p ;y++)` or something else. (*Pointed out by*  `Djon`).

*Moreover if you are trying to find number is prime or not you must go for other logic as your logic is not correct.*

Comment: And what about `p` never being used?

Comment: This is the only answer so far that pointed out all the problems, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Because your loop is never executed. `y=1` is never lower then `x=1.`

Comment: This isn't the only reason this code does not work properly, you should address the other issues as well. (And correct "lower thAn").

Answer (score 1):

For loop never executed because `1<1` is always `false`, therefore it will return `false`

you can determine prime number as simple as this:

```
 public static boolean isPrime(int p){
        for(int y = 2 ; y < p ; y++){
            if(p % y == 0){
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```